# replacing black background with another image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to replace all black pixels in an image with pixels of another image...

this is the code I have so far-

```
imgFront = cv2.imread('withoutbackground.jpg')
imgBack = cv2.imread('background.jpg')

height, width = img.shape[:2]

resizeBack = cv2.resize(imgBack, (width, height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        pixel = imgFront[j, i]
        if pixel == [255, 255, 255]:
            imgFront[j, i] = resizeBack[j, i]
```

however I am getting an error message that says incorrect syntax on this part --

```
pixel = imgFront[j, i]
```

which is weird because I am looking right at the opencv documentation and thats how it says to do it..

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is correct, but there are some minor mistakes.

First, in line 3, it should be the shape of `imgFront` right?:

```
height, width = imgFront.shape[:2]
```

Second, in line `if pixel == [255, 255, 255]:` you should change it to :

```
np.all(pixel == [0, 0, 0])
```

as black color should be (0,0,0)

All in all, the following code works fine for me:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

imgFront = cv2.imread('withoutbackground.jpg')
imgBack = cv2.imread('background.jpg')

height, width = imgFront.shape[:2]

resizeBack = cv2.resize(imgBack, (width, height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        pixel = imgFront[j, i]
        if np.all(pixel == [0, 0, 0]):
            imgFront[j, i] = resizeBack[j, i]
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe it is possible to make a .jpg background transparent (see post: [Transparent background in JPEG image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906144/transparent-background-in-jpeg-image).

You can try PNG or GIF instead.

Comment: I dont think he wants to make it transparent but change with another image

Comment: His original code showed that he set the background pixels to transparent, and then saved the output to a JPEG, and then he asks why the background is black.