# Converting Bytes to a transparent image

Tags: c#, arrays, image-processing, transparency

I already faced the issue with inserting a transparent image to `sql` by `MemoryStream` and I fixed it with `File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)`, `MemoryStream` doesn't make the transparent areas right and now for getting that image right I don't know what should I do. I searched posts from stack overflow and also other websites, there was posts about inserting a transparent image to sql but didn't noticed any about this

```
 using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bitmap)))
 {
     image.Save(Address, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
 }
```

Does anyone knows how can I convert bytes to a transparent image right
tnx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent background in JPEG image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906144/transparent-background-in-jpeg-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving your image to a JPEG-file. JPEG-images do not support transparancy. You could use PNG- or GIF-images. They both support transparancy.