# html blend image into background color

Tags: html, css, image, png, jpeg

I have a html page, back ground is red color. i posted to images, one image the back ground color blends in, other it doesn't. I get white patches. how do i solve it?

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/2otsevhL/3/)

The left image in the link is not blending with background colors.

```
<html>
   <body style="background-color:red;">
      <img alt="Qries" src="https://www.workspez.com/my/images/whoweareserving.jpg"
         width=150" height="70">
      <img alt="Qries" src="https://www.workspez.com/my/images/section4img.png"
         width=150" height="70">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your image should have a transparent background to blend with your red background.

Comment: It's kind of hard to provide `jpg` files with transparent background, so use `png` with transparent background so that there'll not be any white patches.

Comment: Perhaps this thread already answers the question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906144/transparent-background-in-jpeg-image/16906178

Comment: how to have a  transparent background? My white back ground still shows up with a .png file

Answer (score 0):

The image on the left does not have a transparent background. If you want to blend the image with the background, try removing the background from the image, and I guess that will do the job.

Comment: 'try removing the background from the image'  how do i remove the white background?