# How to make backgroud transparent while make image from string text in c#?

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap

I am converting string text to image in c#. It's converting text to image properly but I need image with transparent background. I have try a lot with google r&d but none of that is working.

My code is as below :

```
string fullName = name.Trim();
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
string fontName = "Airin.ttf";
PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
privateFontCollection.AddFontFile(Server.MapPath("~/Content/fontCss/" + fontName));
FontFamily ff = privateFontCollection.Families[0];
Font font = new Font(ff, 25, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
int width = (int)graphics.MeasureString(fullName, font).Width;
int height = (int)graphics.MeasureString(fullName, font).Height;
bitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.Transparent);
bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap, new Size(width, height));
graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
graphics.Clear(Color.White);
graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
graphics.DrawString(fullName, font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";
bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedDocuments/") + fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
fileName = "/UploadedDocuments/" + fileName;
```

So where am I need to change code here for get image with transparent backgroud ?

Comment: What result you get and what you want instead?

Comment: I am getting here image with white background however I need image with transparent background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the image in a format that supports transparencies, such as GIF or PNG. JPEG does not.

[Transparent background in JPEG image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906144/transparent-background-in-jpeg-image/16906178#:%7E:text=7%20Answers&text=You%20can%27t%20make%20a,if%20you%20edit%20the%20file.)

Change the `ImageFormat` parameter at the end of the following line to an appropriate value (e.g. `ImageFormat.Gif` or `ImageFormat.Png`)

```
bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedDocuments/") + fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Also, have you tried changing

```
graphics.Clear(Color.White);
```

to use `Color.Transparent` instead?

Comment: I have try with .Png but still it's showing background white instead of transparent.

Comment: @HarryR I have added a suggestion to change the colour you use for the `graphics.Clear()` call. Graphics aren't really my thing, but it would be the next thing I'd try.

Comment: @HarryR Tested and it's working in LinqPad if you use `graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent);` and save to PNG.