# White background in react-native-view-shot

Tags: react-native, react-native-view-shot

I am using [react-native-view-shot](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot) to save a screenshot of a view, whose height is not initially defined, as I am using padding and setting the height of the view using the `onLayout` method.

The problem is that, when the view has an initial fixed height, the screenshot taken does not have a white background, which is what I want. However, when I set the height when the onLayout is invoked, the screenshot has a white background.

Here's my code:

```
const [height, setHeight] = useState();

  <View
    onLayout={(e) => {
      setHeight(e.nativeEvent.layout.height);
    }}
    ref={contentRef}
    style={{
      height,
      width: width - 12,
      backgroundColor: "darkblue",
      borderRadius: 32,
    }}
  >
    <Text style={styles.text}>This is a test using padding</Text>
  </View>
```

> https://snack.expo.dev/@pietroputelli/react-native-view-shot

=========== EDIT ===========

```
 <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <View ref={shotRef} style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}>
        <View
          onLayout={(e) => {
            setHeight(e.nativeEvent.layout.height);
          }}
          style={{
            height,
            width: width / 2 - 12,
            backgroundColor: "darkblue",
            borderRadius: 32,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>This is a test using padding</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          captureRef(shotRef, {
            format: "png",
            quality: 0.8,
          }).then(
            async (uri) => {
              await MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(uri);
            },
            (error) => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
          );
        }}
        title="Take screenshot"
      />
    </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get transparency when I set the format to `"png"` in the options parameter for `captureRef`. PNGs can show a transparency, "jpgs" cannot:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906144/transparent-background-in-jpeg-image#:~:text=JPEG%20can't%20support%20transparency,%2C%20a%20%3D%20alpha%20value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906144/transparent-background-in-jpeg-image#:%7E:text=JPEG%20can%27t%20support%20transparency,%2C%20a%20%3D%20alpha%20value)).

(And for me, I was trying to show rounded corners. I just had to set the outer component style to have `borderRadius` with no background colour, but the child had a `backgroundColor`)

```
const viewRef = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<ViewShot>;

// ... 

const onClickDownload = async () => {
  try {
     const uri = await captureRef(viewRef, {
       fileName: entryFilename,
       format: "png", 
       quality: 0.9,
     });

     // ... 
  } 
}
```

Using: https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot

Answer (score 0):

I can able to generate the same from viewshot:
take another view and give a reference to that view and generate a screenshot from that. might be its issue of reference. Please check the below screenshot.

[image]

```
            <View ref={viewshotRef}
                style={{
                    // whatever you want to add as per your requirement 
                }} >
                <View
                    onLayout={(e) => {
                        setHeight(e.nativeEvent.layout.height);
                    }}
                    style={{
                        height,
                        width: DEVICE_WIDTH / 2 - 12,
                        backgroundColor: "darkblue",
                        borderRadius: 32,
                    }}
                >
                    <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>This is a test using padding</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
```

For base64:

```
import * as MediaLibrary from "expo-media-library";
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
    Button,
    Dimensions,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
} from "react-native";
import ViewShot, { captureRef } from "react-native-view-shot";

const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");

export default function ViewCapture() {
    const contentRef = useRef();

    const [height, setHeight] = useState(undefined);

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "transparent" }}>
            <ViewShot ref={contentRef} options={{ result: 'base64' }}>
                <View
                    onLayout={(e) => {
                        setHeight(e.nativeEvent.layout.height);
                    }}
                    style={{
                        height,
                        width: width - 12,
                        backgroundColor: "darkblue",
                        borderRadius: 32,
                    }}
                >
                    <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>This is a test using padding</Text>
                </View>
            </ViewShot>
            {/* </View> */}

            <Button
                onPress={() => {
                    contentRef.current.capture().then((url) => {
                        console.log("on success", "data:image/jpeg;base64,", url)
                        //   await MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(uri);
                    },
                        (error) => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
                    );
                }}
                title="Take screenshot"
            />
        </View>

    );
}
```

For File:

You need to set the result as tmpfile so you will get file uri in the callback

```
   <ViewShot ref={contentRef} options={{ result: 'tmpfile' }}>
```

I hope it will work!

Comment: Thank you, but your background is still white, I want it to be tranparent.

Comment: you can set `backgroundColor:'transparent'`

Comment: It does't work anyway.

Comment: above code work perfectly in my sample

Comment: the background of what trasnparent, your screen has a white background

Comment: Can you please help me by explaining better, thank you very much

Comment: View has another parent View, that parent View backgroundColor you can set according to your requirement

Comment: I cant get it, if you can please so me the code, it would really help me. thanks a lot

Comment: please check the Updated answer and use the first view reference

Comment: I have updated the question, and using this code it has the white background.

Comment: please check the working example in the updated answer with file and base 64, I hope it works for you!  Don't forget to accept & upvote the answer.

Comment: It does't work again

Comment: What's the error? It's a working example.

Comment: I still have the white background.